# What type should I use for browser elements in typescript in wdio tests?

Tags: typescript, testing, webdriver-io, wdio

I'm trying to figure out how to type browser elements. Code example (??? marks the place where you need to add the type):

```
login_input = await $('div.login_input')
await set_login('login', login_input)

set_login = async (
  login: string, login_input: ???
): Promise<void> => {
  await login_input.setValue(login);
}
```

This source https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/7767 says that for browser elements you need to use the type **ChainablePromiseElement<Promise< Element>>**, but if i do it, i have this error: **Type 'ChainablePromiseElement' is not generic**

I would be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the wdio support chat. Need to use type **WebdriverIO.Element**

```
set_login = async (
  login: string, login_input: WebdriverIO.Element
): Promise<void> => {
  await login_input.setValue(login);
}
```